# What is the difference between the property syntax style _suit and suit in the implementation (for example)?

Tags: objective-c

In the objective c book i read the author always use property objects in the implementation like:

(I know we dont use synthesize anymore, unless we overriding the setter AND getter, but just for the example)

`@synthesize suit, rank;`

and in the stanford course if he need to use @synthesize he do:

`@synthesize suit = _suit;`

`@synthesize rank = _rank;`

and its getting me confused a bit. Is the `_rank` is to set the object to some value while the `rank` is to get it?

if yes, so the line: `@synthesize rank = _rank;` confuses me a bit...

would love to get some direction.
tnx

Comment: This subject has been covered rather extensively already.  You're better off looking at the "duplicates" rather than relying on an answer here.  One thing to keep in mind, though, is that things changed somewhat with the more recent versions of Xcode, and with ARC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `@synthesize rank = _rank;`

This instructs the compiler to generate a setter and/or getter as needed, using an ivar called `_rank` as the backing instance variable. It will create the ivar `_rank` if needed. [edit], meaning if it does not already exist.[/edit]

> `@synthesize rank;`

This instructs the compiler to generate a setter and/or getter as needed using an ivar called `rank` (same name as the property itself)

And then with LLVM4, if you don't explicitly ask the compiler to @synthesize a @property, and you rely on the compiler to do this by default for you, then it will create an ivar called `_rank` by default.

Comment: Just a small nitpick: iVars are created whether or not they are used, so `_rank` will *always* be generated, even if it's not needed.

Comment: @CodaFi will the compiler create _rank if it already exists?